# Checking if a string escaped

Tags: ruby

I have 3 strings:

```
#1 アンジェリーナ・ジョリー
#2 %E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC
#3 Angelina_Jolie
```

1. How do I recognize #2 from other strings, in other words, how do I check if the method `CGI.escape` (from Ruby or any other method that does the same thing) has been applied to a given string?
2. How do I **easily** check that a string **should or can** be escaped, in other words, if one applies `CGI.escape` to a string, the result will be different from the original string? In this case, #1 can be escaped, whereas #3 not.

Comment: You just said how it's done. Apply escape to it and compare to the original. If they are different, it can be escaped, if not, it can't. It's funny how explaining something to others matches the code so closely.

Comment: This is _technically_ impossible. How do you know that #2 isn't _supposed_ to be the literal string `%E3%82...` and doesn't need to be escaped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to assume that if a string contains escapable characters *other than escape sequences*, it needs to be escaped. For example `%3E` doesn't need to be escaped, but `%3E>` should be escaped to `%253E%3E`. You can check for such characters by comparing the string to itself after unescaping and re-escaping:

```
def CGI.maybe_escape str
  return str if str == escape(unescape(str))
  escape str
end

CGI.maybe_escape('>')
# "%3E"
CGI.maybe_escape(CGI.maybe_escape('%3E>'))
# "%253E%3E" <-- only escapes once!
```

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'cgi'
=> true
```

and

```
irb(main):002:0> x = "アンジェリーナ・ジョリー"
irb(main):003:0> y = "%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC"
irb(main):005:0> z = "Angelina_Jolie"
```

To tell that a string has already been escaped once, compare the string with its unescaped value:

```
irb(main):141:0> x == CGI::unescape(x)
=> true
irb(main):142:0> y == CGI::unescape(y)
=> false
irb(main):143:0> z == CGI::unescape(z)
=> true
```

Here you can see that `y == CGI::unescape(y)` returns `false`. As long as you are sure that the escape characters in your string were due to the application of `CGI::escape` that should give you the answer you desire. I believe that answers your first question.

If the string can/should be escaped then `false` will be returned in the following comparison:

```
irb(main):017:0> CGI::escape(CGI::unescape(x)) == CGI::unescape(CGI::escape(x))
=> false
irb(main):018:0> CGI::escape(CGI::unescape(y)) == CGI::unescape(CGI::escape(y))
=> true
irb(main):019:0> CGI::escape(CGI::unescape(z)) == CGI::unescape(CGI::escape(z))
=> true
```

Without the first step above in my answer, that doesn't allow you to distinguish between type `y` and type `z`, that is, you can't tell that `y` has already been escaped and `z` never needed it, but at least you know you do not need to apply escape again. I think that is the answer to your second question.

Answer (score 1):

Identifying whether a string should be escaped by whether a string can be escaped has no value.

The only situation when a string will not be changed by escaping it is if there is nothing to escape. In this situation, there is negligible cost from escaping again:

```
CGI.escape(CGI.escape(CGI.escape('foo')))  == 'foo'
```

If there is something to escape, the characters added by escaping will themselves be escapable:

```
CGI.escape('<b>foo</b>')                         == "%3Cb%3Efoo%3C%2Fb%3E" 
CGI.escape(CGI.escape('<b>foo</b>'))             == "%253Cb%253Efoo%253C%252Fb%253E"
CGI.escape(CGI.escape(CGI.escape('<b>foo</b>'))) == '%25253Cb%25253Efoo%25253C%25252Fb%25253E'
```

So escaping again does not distinguish something that can be escaped but has not already been escaped, from something that can be escaped and has already been escaped.

I think the only certain solution it to make sure you only escape once.