# Elegant way to html escape string that may already have been escaped

Tags: html, ruby, escaping

I have a string that may or may not be escaped for HTML. I want to ensure escaping.

When the string is not escaped, `CGI.escapeHTML` works as expected:

`"queen's"` -> `"queen&#39;s"`

However, when the string is pre-escaped, it does not give the correct result:

`"queen&#39;s"` -> `"queen&amp;#39;s"`

One solution is to call `CGI.unescapeHTML`  prior to calling `CGI.escapeHTML`. Any way to do this in a less hacky way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a string escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846734/checking-if-a-string-escaped)

Comment: Calling a single method to ensure something is not hacky at all. It is the normal way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `CGI::unescapeHTML` prior to calling `GCI::escapeHTML` is the simplest and most straightforward way to accomplish this.

For example:

```
require 'cgi'

def to_escapedHTML
  CGI::escapeHTML(CGI::unescapeHTML(self))
end

pp to_escapedHTML("queen&#39;s")
```